# why is my Event not working in octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to wrap my head around octobercms group and permission. I added a great  [plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/kurtjensen-passage) on permission and role that is straight forward and easy to implement on page/users but my question is do I have to add all users to group manually from the backend like one by one?

I created a new plugin and in the Plugin.php file I have this, 
`use Event; //on the top of the file`

I have this in its boot method to add users to the group with code `seller` on registration.

```
    public function boot()
{

Event::listen('rainlab.user.register', function($user){
    $group = 
    \Rainlab\User\Models\UserGroup::where('code', 'seller')->first();

    $user->groups()->add($group);
    $user->save();
});
```

Doesn't seem to work. what am I missing in all of these?

plugin.php file

```
<?php namespace Corymillz\Newplug;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Event;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
   public function registerComponents()
    {
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }

   public function boot()
{ 

Event::listen('rainlab.user.register', function($user,$postdata){
    $group = \Rainlab\User\Models\UserGroup::where('code', 'seller')->first();

    $user->groups = $group->id;
    $user->save();
});


}

}
```

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Comment: Yes I just did. Plugin doesn't disappear any more but it still doesn't add the user to group

Comment: The event rainlab.user.register fired only from front-end. I hope you are using it from front-end

Comment: Yes I am. I created a new plugin and the code is in the plugin.php file

Comment: please completely paste your boot method of plugin.php file.

Comment: I have updated it above. That is my entire plugin.php file

Comment: Got it working replacing ``register`` with ``activate``. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Can you tell me what is your octobercms and rainlab.user plugin versions ? because if you are on submitting form from front-end by using **Account** component then register event must have been fired.

Comment: and by the way the code I have given you in my answer worked. right ?

Answer (score 0):

just change your code like that.

```
Event::listen('rainlab.user.register', function($user,$postdata){
    $group = \Rainlab\User\Models\UserGroup::where('code', 'seller')->first();

    $user->groups = $group->id;
    $user->save();
});
```